# Counter Column; Divide rows in table by nrows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am struggling with the following:

```
Counter --- Period ---
 1         2012-02-09 
 1         2012-02-09 
 1         2012-02-08 
 2         2012-02-07 
 2         2012-02-07
 2         2012-02-07 
 3         2012-02-06
 3         2012-02-06
```

I don't know what function to use or how to add a counter column that will divide the period rows in the table by 3 and add a counts. It will divide until it can and assign the leftover rows as the next counter (as shown above). In the example above @n is 3 so it counts each period assigns 1 until 3 are complete and counters.

I have looked at NTILE that does not work as it just divides it into n groups.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you need to clarify your question; if I use `NTILE()` I get the result you're looking for (if you include an ID):

```
declare @tableA table(id int identity, col1 date)

insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-09')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-09')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-08')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-07')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-07')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-07')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-06')
insert into @tableA values ('2012-02-06')

select ntile(3) over (order by id) counter, col1 Period from @tableA
```

Results:

```
counter              Period
-------------------- ----------
1                    2012-02-09
1                    2012-02-09
1                    2012-02-08
2                    2012-02-07
2                    2012-02-07
2                    2012-02-07
3                    2012-02-06
3                    2012-02-06
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like:

```
declare @n as int = 3

SELECT
((ROW_NUMBER() over (order by period desc) - 1) / @n) + 1 as counter,
[period]
FROM [a].[dbo].[a]
```

Comment: It shifts the integer assigned by ROW_NUMBER down by one. So when using integer division against @n, the integer that would usually divide equally does not and it will be the last one in the group. For example, if @n is three, 0,1,2 go into the first group, 3,4,5 go into second...